# Working with PHP mime mail parser

Tags: email-parsing

I'm using this library to parse my incoming emails:
http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

I have Mailparse extension installed and everything is fine, but when I do:

```
echo $from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
```

It echos out the `name` of the email sender, for example: `John Smith`, but I need the `email` address of the email sender, for example `john@smith.com`.

This also happens for:

```
echo $to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
```

and I can't seem to find any solution to get these, any helps here?
Thanks in adnva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply `htmlspecialchars()` function on to/from:

```
// You need to apply htmlspecialchars() function on to/from:
$from = htmlspecialchars($Parser->getHeader('from'));
$to = htmlspecialchars($Parser->getHeader('to'));

// the above code will give you something like:
// John Smith <john@smith.com>
// so to get the email address we need to use explode() function:

function get_email_address($input){
        $input = explode('&lt;', $input);
        $output = str_replace('&gt;', '', $input);
        $name = $output[0]; // THE NAME
        $email = $output[1]; // THE EMAIL ADDRESS
        return $email;
}

$from = htmlspecialchars($Parser->getHeader('from'));
echo $from = get_email_address($from); // NOW THIS IS THE EMAIL

$to = htmlspecialchars($Parser->getHeader('to'));
echo $from = get_email_address($to) // NOW THIS IS THE EMAIL
```